# I'm trying to install OpenGraph gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, facebook-opengraph

I've searched entire web looking for a way to get over this error. But it won't budge. I installed all the libraries and dependencies according to my knowledge even uninstalled ruby and nokogiri and reinstalled again. But this error remains here.

```html
Gem files will remain installed in /home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/nokogiri-1.4.7/gem_make.out
```

This is from the gem_make.out log file  from this location -> /.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/nokogiri-1.4.7/gem_make.out

```html
ERROR:  Error installing opengraph:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7/ext/nokogiri
/home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20171125-15877-nibcps.rb extconf.rb --with-nokogiri-dir=/home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/home/$User/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
               CONFIG

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I'd be very thankful to you if you could tell me what's wrong with it. Is it a bug in OpenGraph.

**P.S: I'm not using opengraph_parser because it has a fallback method. I need opengraph gem because I need to catch the exception.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not opengraph, but rather nokogiri.

Nokogiri is a dependency for opengraph.
https://rubygems.org/gems/opengraph/versions/0.0.4

So, it must be related on your machine not having the dependencies needed to support nokogiri (libxml2).

Install these dependencies on your machine (assuming your on **Debian/Ubuntu**):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

**Fedora/Red Hat/CentOS:**

```
sudo yum install -y gcc ruby-devel zlib-devel
sudo yum install -y rubygem-nokogiri (alternative)
```

Then try installing nokogiri by `gem install nokogiri`

For other variants, or OS:
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

For Fedora 26:
Until further notice, install nokogiri version < 1.8

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying. But I'm using Fedora 26. Can you tell me similar dependencies for Fedora or any Redhat.

Comment: @Meimo ruby-devel zlib-devel. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying again but I when I tried to install these dependencies...terminal said "already installed. Nothing to do". See I told you everything is installed according to my knowledge. But it just won't install. I think it's a bug.

Comment: @Meimo Try installing nokogiri using system libraries `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
`

Comment: You'd be surprised @jemensanto , but I've tried that already. It's installed using system libraries presently

Comment: @Meimo try installing a nokogiri gem below 1.8 like nokogiri 1.7.2. Somehow, there's a compatibility issue with Fedora 26 and nokogiri 1.8
See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1482641